# Image is displayed wrong on static image layer on top of osf layer

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I followed the [example](http://www.acuriousanimal.com/thebookofopenlayers3/chapter02_04_image_layer.html) from the openlayers book to add a static image on top of an osf layer. It works, but my image (256x256) is displayed as a rectangle. I tried around with the coordinates for the projection and checked out other posts here on, but I can't get my head around it why the image is not displayed as a square:

```
// Create map
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map', // The DOM element that will contains the map
  renderer: 'canvas', // Force the renderer to be used
  layers: [
    // Add a new Tile layer getting tiles from OpenStreetMap source
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  // Create a view centered on the specified location and zoom level
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([16.3725, 48.208889], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 4
  })
});

// Create an image layer
var imageLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
  opacity: 0.75,
  source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
    attributions: [
      new ol.Attribution({
        html: ''
      })
    ],
    url: 'https://placebear.com/256/256',
    imageSize: [256, 256],
    projection: map.getView().getProjection(),
    imageExtent: ol.extent.applyTransform(
      [0, 0, 16.3725, 48.208889], ol.proj.getTransform("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"))
  })
});

map.addLayer(imageLayer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ol.source.ImageStatic` was made to put a georeferenced image (e.g. a scan of a historic map) on a map. Is this what you have in mind? If you just want to display an image and anchor it to a location on the map, you'd better use `ol.Overlay` or an `ol.layer.Vector` with a feature with an `ol.style.Icon`.

That said, your image will only be displayed as square if the `imageExtent` set on your `ol.source.ImageStatic` results in a square on the projected map view.

Comment: Thanks for a clarification, in fact I want to show an overlay image, e.g a strategic map on top. Regarding the image projection, I was confused how to calculate the lat/long coordinates from the pixels. Is there a way I can calculate lat/long from a starting point and simply say, go x metres in the south (if I say that a pixel is one metre)?

Comment: I now added it as an overly which does the thing as expected. So my question is now obsolete.

Comment: @ChristophS I'm trying to do the same thing here, adding a PNG image (which is a detailed map of an area) on top. Could you share your solution?

Comment: @RegisCamimura I created a gist with two possible solutions. I used the first one in a previous phase of my project and the second one is my current solution: https://gist.github.com/Siedlerchr/d920a132e30adcd84c509597cf421549

For the second one you need two coordinate pairs of two corners, leftBottom and rightTop where you want to place your image